# How can i create an animation scene by scene in paraview using python script

Tags: python, paraview

Good evening,
I have a series of vtk files.
I wrote a script that performs a specific rotation of those files and then using
    animationScene1.GoToNext()
goes to the next scene, a new rotation is performed e.t.c.
How can i also add the newly created scene to an video format output?
In short, i want every time the script jumps to a new scene and rotation to save the old one and in the end have a video with the correct rotation per scene
Thank you very much for your time

Comment: When using ParaView GUI, did you setup the animation so it can be played when pressing the play button ? If Yes, save animation should just work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however the rotations are generated and done via a python script and save animation will only take effect after it. I ideally want to run the script and at the same time produce the animation

Comment: so you have two possiblities : either save each images yourself in python, or implement your rotation as a standard animation procedure. See Animation View -> Camera

Comment: Thanks,
in set animation view camera is there a way to import ~10000 positions automatically?
if not, how do i save each image in python?

Comment: There is no way to import camera position yet. To save an image in pvpython use `SaveScreenshot("path/to/yourFile.png")`.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion @MathieuWestphal solved it

Comment: great, please accept my anwer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are moving the camera to specific position using a python script, the easiest way will be to save the images yourself in your script using

```
SaveScreenshot("path/to/your/imageN.png")
```

And then reconstruct a video from all the images.